# "puppet resource user" shows all users

Tags: puppet

If I run `puppet resource user` on a puppet node, it lists all users defined on the machine (from `/etc/password` ).
All users have `ensure => 'present'` attribute. 
Shouldn't it list only the users in the classes that apply to this node ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `puppet resource` command is a facility that helps in converting current system state into `puppet` `dsl` code.

From the output of `puppet help resource`:

```
DESCRIPTION
-----------
This command provides simple facilities for converting current system
state into Puppet code, along with some ability to modify the current
state using Puppet's RAL.
```

Hope this helps.